# Disable a button before calling a method

Tags: components, zk

I want to disable a button before calling a method.
In other words, I want to execute some codes as linear.

Here is the code

```
@Listen("onClick = #kodIsteButtonId")
public void kodIste() {
   k = kd.findKisiByKullaniciadi(kullaniciadiId.getValue());
   if (k == null) {
         Messagebox.show("Böyle bir kullanıcı bulunamadı!", "Hata Mesajı",
            0, Messagebox.ERROR);
    } else {
         kodIsteButtonId.setDisabled(true);
         countDown(10, 6, k);
    }
}

private void countDown(int fromToZero, int sleepTime, Kisiler k) {
  tempPassword = rasgeleYeniSifre();
  sendEposta(k.getEposta(), tempPassword);
  alert("Güvenlik kodu e-postanıza gönderildi.");
  while (fromToZero > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    fromToZero--;
}
   sifreAlButtonId.setDisabled(false);
   clearButtonId.setDisabled(false);
   kodId.setDisabled(false);
}
```

When I click the button I want to see it disabled.
But after running the countDown() method, it is still enabled.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: Thanks for formatting @DerGolem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the button disable the moment you get an answer back from the server.
For your case this is the moment that `public void kodIste()` is finished.

The most easiest solution is to use the autodisable :

```
<button autodisable="self" />
```

This disable and enable the button automaticly.
If you want to control when the button has to enable itself again you can do :

```
<button autodisable="+self" />
```

[Documentation can be found here.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Button#Autodisable)